# TFS combine two change sets into one in the same branch

Tags: .net, tfs, changeset

I have change set 50195 and 50196. The first check-in is 90% of the work for a work item, and the second is the other 10%. I want to be able to combine these two changes set's into one, so 100% of the work for that work item can be rolled back in one change set. Is this possible? I've seen posts around merging change sets into a branch, but not combining two change sets into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is doable auto-magically.

how about rolling back to the change-set just before 50195,  and then re-creating all your changes and check them in at once.

if you save local copies of the changes in 50195 & 50196, you could use the merge tool to push the changes into your new single change-set quickly.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, and I can certainly do this. Through my research, I've also found there is no real way of auto-magically doing this. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I achieve it with the steps below:

1. Pick those few changesets and select roll back for each of them.
2. Now they are all in my Pending Changes.
3. Check-in the pending changes into a changeset, eg changeset 12345.
4. Rollback the changeset 12345 into pending changes, the pending changes will be the combination of the few changesets.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in this: ExtendedMerge

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/96ca3487-ef76-4c99-8e9e-0d4ae53a11f9

Comment: Very cool link. We actually moved to 2012, and are on the verge of 2013 TFS, so this won't help for me, but I'm sure it may help someone on 2010, so +1 for you.

Comment: Link is dead now.